# How to target a specific row when a condition is made with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a specific color to one specific row only when this row has the class glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign. So far, I've done this code but it's still not working (It targets all the rows). The end result would be something like this.

```
$("div").addClass(function(index, currentClass) {
var addedClass;
if (currentClass === "fu-icon1") {
    addedClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign";
    $(".table tr").addClass("success");
} else if (currentClass === "fu-icon0") {
    addedClass = "glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign";
    $(".table tr").addClass("danger");
}
return addedClass;
});
```

[image]

Comment: and what is the $('div') ??  provide html  or create a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: The div is for adding a class to one specific cell

 class="fu-icon1 glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"

As you can see in the if(){} as this div has the class fu-icon I add the glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign.

Comment: can u copy your html here? the problem with your code is that you're applying "success" or "danger" class to all the rows by this $(".table tr").addClass("danger" or "success");

Comment: but how can we know the relation between div  and the row you need to add classes to it?? again please provide html or create a demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.fu-icon1').each(function() {
   $(this).parent('tr').addClass('success');
   $(this).addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign");
   });
});

$('.fu-icon0').each(function() {
   $(this).parent('tr').addClass('danger');
   $(this).addClass("glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign");
   });
});
```